# Are any furies based on specific Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon, codex-alera

We [know](http://www.fantasyliterature.com/author-interviews/jim-butcher/) that [furies](http://codexalera.wikia.com/wiki/Furies#Named_furies) in Codex Alera are based on [Pokémon](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_(creature)), in that they’re elemental  creatures that  can take on various forms. However, are any of them based on *specific* Pokémon, in appearance or conceit? For example, is there a large, fiery dragon-shaped fury ([Charizard](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Charizard)) or a water fury shaped like a giant turtle ([Blastoise](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Blastoise))?

Comment: Wow did I misread that question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**None of the furies or Great Furies appear to have any direct link to specific Pokemon.**

There is an [SDCC interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylKRYe0ZWHo) where Jim Butcher, while going into the creation of Codex Alera, mentions that digging into Pokemon showed him that the root idea is that there are spirits in everywhere and everything, a concept from Shintoism.  That is what formed the core of Codex Alera.

Since there are so many Pokemon, it is possible to draw some minor similarities.  There are plenty of dog-types that might resemble Brutus, there are several horses that might remind you of Cirrus.  The sheer variety of wild furies seen near the end of the series means there's probably plenty of coincidental matches too - any element of fury appears to be able to take any shape, although there are certain common trends (windmanes are all very similar).  Nothing given any major screen time in the series appears to be a direct match (I've found an earth horse, and a water horse, and a fire dog).

So while Pokemon was listed as a building block for the series, it doesn't look like he drew from specific creatures in that franchise.

Comment: Fire dog is Growlithe. ;)

Comment: @Adamant I guess there were fire dogs in and on the cover of Captain's Fury now that I think of it... but they really *really* didn't look like that.